# <input type="color" Не хочет работать

Tags: color, php, html, css, форма

Нужно в форме настроек вывести поле для выбора цвета. 
Пытаюсь высести следуйщим  способом.

```
echo '<input name="color" type="color" value="'.$color.'" style="width:370px"><br>';
```

Переменная $color имеет значение #ff0022, в результате, получаю обычное текстовое поле со значением #ff0022.

Возникает вопрос: почему не работает атрибут type="color" и как сделать вывод диалога выбора цвета?

Comment: А [этот][1] пример у Вас работает?


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/mtxj4/

Comment: В том то и дело что нерабочий.... вопрос почему? всюду пишет что поле <input type="color"> сллужыт для вібора цвета, при клике должно появится всплівающее окно с цветовойпалитрой для выбора цвета, но почему-то ничего не происходит, пробовал несколькими браузерами эфкекта ноль.

Comment: Какой браузер?

Comment: @DreamChild в опере почему-то тоже... хром и яндекс браузер пашет нормально ((( а как тогда в мазиле такое сделать?

Comment: @arashvg обновил информацию  в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный тэг работает не во всех браузерах. А именно - в Chrome - с 20-ой версии, в Opera - с 11.0 по 12.1 и с 17-ой по текущую (вот такой вот сюрприз, очевидно, разрыв связан со сменой браузерного движка с Presto на Webkit), в Firefox планируется только с 28-ой (текущая - 26-ая), в IE его нет вообще. Подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](http://caniuse.com/input-color)

Comment: кстати забавный баг сайта: 

http://i.imgur.com/f8DsYDT.png

очевидно, связан с тем, что в названии вопроса содержится html-тэг

Comment: Осталось только создать вопрос с JS в заголовке и тырить сессию...

Answer (score 2):

Проблема у Вас с браузером. Варианта всего два:

- Не поддерживать этот браузер в разрабатываемом сайте;
- Использовать кроссбраузерное решение: [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/), [menucool](http://www.menucool.com/), [farbtastic](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input
Тут поддержка разных инпутов разными браузерами. FF с 27-й версии будет поддерживать.